# Visual Studio ISO files downloaded, how do I run? Do I need virtual drive tool?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, virtual-machine, virtual-drive

I have Visual Studio 2010 Pro on a DVD disc, but it is an ISO image, and I wanted to run this on my home PC in place of 2010 Express Edition.

So first of all, can I run this on my home computer? Do I need a virtual drive tool to run an image on my home computer? Is there a microsoft virtual drive tool? Is there a good resource I could read about this and learn the basics.

Comment: 7zip will let you extract files from isos: http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm) to mount and install from iso images.  It's freeware and there are versions for Windows XP through Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 8 and newer come with built-in ISO mounting support. Just associate `.iso` with `explorer.exe` (if they're not) and double-click on them. Windows'll mount it to the first available drive letter (excluding `A:` and `B:`) and will "eject" on shutdown.

Comment: Can also be extracted with any zip utility. I used WinRAR.

Answer (score 17):

Use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract files to some folder.

Comment: I wanted to try this however, if I try to download my AV indicates that is includes spyware/adware??

Comment: @Justin What antivirus are you using?

Comment: is just the generic McAfee Security Center

Comment: Thank you, its simple and straight forward

Comment: Thanks. I forgot you could do this. i'm glad i looked a little further before installing something else.

Answer (score 5):

[Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html)

Supports all common image formats such as ISO, BIN, CCD

Supports up to 8 virtual drives at the same time

Easy to use - just double-click an image file to mount as a drive

Virtual CloneDrive is freeware, you may use it at no cost.

Comment: Hey thanks for the link. This ended up working out the best for me I think!

Comment: It gets no easier! Just install this and then double click the ISO file, and it mounts and autoruns just like you inserted a DVD!

Answer (score 2):

[Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads) is a tool capable of mounting ISO files as "fake" CD or DVD drives.  Once that has been done you can just run the install program off there as if it was a standard disc in your system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mount it as a virtual disk (basically making it look like a DVD in your drive to Windows). I don't use Windows (as I'm a Linux person), but one of these should work (can't post links): PowerISO or Daemon Tools Lite.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a normal disk you can use "dvdburn" (search google for "dvdburn microsoft"). Or check if your Vista/windows 7 shell allows you to burn it by right click (it exists as shell feature in later Windows-es)

Answer (score 0):

Installing [`ImDisk Toolkit`](http://reboot.pro/files/file/284-imdisk-toolkit/) will add "Mount as ImDisk Virtual Disk" item to your Windows context menu.

[image: Imgur]

Then following dialog pops up:

[image: Imgur]

And it actually works:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

Not trusting any third party/potentially malware iso mounting options, I ended up just downloading it again. Microsoft has a second download option that is an exe instead of an iso.

Comment: You could just burn it into a dvd. Windows has default dvd burner application.

Comment: @Jahid my PC doesn't have a DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

WinCDEmu is open source. You can checkout build from their website or Github: https://github.com/sysprogs/WinCDEmu/releases/